# Battleship game: Allowing hits to be registered on ships with lengths other than 4

Tags: javascript

I'm making Battleship in JavaScript for a school project and I'm stuck.

The computer randomly generates boats and the user has to try to sink all the computer's boats by entering in coordinates. The hits on a boat are saved in an array. The array contains zeros to signify the boat's length (so boat with length 4 has an array with 4 zeros). When a boat is hit, the 0 changes to 1. If all the elements are 1, the boat sinks. Problem is my code registers the hits, but only puts it in an array when you hit the boat with length 4.

Can anyone help me? Below is the [code of the "game"](http://pastebin.com/7MeWWDdn) itself:

```
function game() {
    inputArray = [4, 3, 2];
    var boats = randomBoats(inputArray);
    var currentBoat = 0;
    var sunkenBoat = 0;
    var numberOfTurns = 0;
    while (sunkenBoat !== inputArray.length) {
        var hit = false;
        var target = "(" + prompt("Enter targetcoordinate (x,y)") + ")";
        var targetString = target.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        for (var i = 0; i !== inputArray.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j !== boats[i].usedPositions().length; j++) {
                console.log(targetString)
                if (targetString === boats[i].usedPositions()[j].toString()) {
                    raak = true;
                    boats[i].hits[j] = 1;
                    console.log(boats[i].hits);
                    currentBoat = boats[i];
                } else {
                    currentBoat = boats[i];
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(currentBoat.hits);
        console.log(allEquals(currentBoat.hits, 1));
        if (hit)
            alert("Hit!");
        else
            alert("Miss!");
        if (allEquals(currentBoat.hits, 1)) {
            alert("Boat with length " + currentBoat.hits.length + " has sunken!");
            sunkenBoat++;
        }
        numberOfTurns++
    }
    alert("You've won! You did it in " + numberOfTurns + " turns.")
}
```

Comment: Generally we expect all of the relevant code to be included in the question, so that it still makes sense and is useful even if the links to external sites stop working.

Comment: OK, I included the code of the 'game itself', that's where I think the problem is.

Comment: What is usedPositions()?

Comment: @Benubird: it's in the Pastebin link provided in the question: http://pastebin.com/7MeWWDdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the else in the inner loop, as you processed each ship (outer loop) and all positions (inner loop) your

```
else {
    currentBoat = boats[i];
}
```

would always set the current boat to be the last [i];

You also don't need to process any other positions or boats when you've found a hit, so break early when you detect the hit like this:

```
raak = false;
for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length && !raak; i++) {

        for(var j = 0; j !== boats[i].usedPositions().length; j++) {

            console.log(targetString)

            if(targetString === boats[i].usedPositions()[j].toString()) {
                raak = true;
                boats[i].hits[j] = 1;
                console.log(boats[i].hits);
                currentBoat = boats[i];
                break;
            }
       }  
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I've got a different version of the code that includes a visual interface and still have some problems with that too. Can I just edit my question or should I start a new one?

Comment: You, really should start a new question